# Insert image in table

Tags: tables, includegraphics

in my CV i have different sections with tables.

I tried to insert the picture under Personal section, but I didn't get any further with the other forum posts and solutions. Maybe because I don't quite understand how includegraphix works with the environment in tabular.

here is the code and what i like to have. Maybe you guys can help me

```
\begin{rSection}{Persönliches}

\begin{tabular}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{6ex}} l }
Geburtsdatum: \ & 1603 \\
Familienstand: \ & richtig\\
Adresse: \ & street 9\\
        \ & New Spork \\
\end{tabular}

\end{rSection}
```

My aim is to integrate the image in this way. Side to the table.

[image]

thanks for the help!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please a complete executable code to have what You post (without hand correction).

Comment: Welcome. // If you need a checklist, and examples, how to turn a code snippet into a MWE before posting, please find it here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 .

Answer (score 2):

Just add one more column to your tale and insert there in multirow cell desired image:

```
\begin{tabular}{ @{} >{\bfseries}l @{\hspace{6ex}} l r }
Geburtsdatum:   & 1603     & \multirow{3}{*}{\includegraphics[width=22mm]{my image}  \\
Familienstand:  & richtig  &   \\
Adresse:        & street 9 &   \\
                & New Spork &  \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: @luks, if you like to see proposed solution as  complete small document, pleas first edit your question and extend showed code snippet to to it (as you were asked in comments below question.